# ProtoBuf Compile Link GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake, protocol-buffers

I am trying to debug why protobuf is not being linked in my C++ project.

So I tried this in cygwin:

```
$ gcc -libprotobuf
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -libprotobuf
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I built and installed protobuf on cygwin.

Comment: Isn't it `-lprotobuf`?

Comment: I think it should be `-lprotobuf-c`

Comment: @BAR, well maybe you should actually install protobuf then. And before you say you did, if the libraries aren't findable on your system, you didn't.

Comment: @Blindy Using cygwin.  Definitely installed - files in /usr/local/lib.  Got it working in a Linux env, Windows is a hassle... as usual.

Comment: Try CMake 3.6.2, thre was a bugfix for protobuf, maybe you were affected.

Answer (score -1):

it should be -lprotobuf, find libprotobuf.so in /usr/lib or /usr/lib64/

Comment: there is no libprotobuf in /usr/lib

Comment: try cygwin\usr\local\lib, find protobuf install directory, gcc can'g libprotobuf directory result in this, find it and add '-L path' after your command